# decimal issue when adding a flat fee

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a small issue I believe the code is doing exactly what its suppose to be doing I have a function whereby I pass in an amount and I add a flat fee of 40 cents to it for the surcharge.

Below is how my current code is constructed

```
Double surcharge;
surcharge = 0.4 * moneyIn / 100;
```

If I pass 999.00m in as moneyIn it returns 0.3996 when in fact it should return 0.4 I'm unsure what I need to do to make it be 0.4.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `decimal` - you're using `double`. Use `decimal` *everywhere* (so `moneyIn` should be a `decimal` too). If you're actually using `999.00m` for `moneyIn`, that would make it a `decimal` and your current code wouldn't even compile (as there are no implicit conversions between `decimal` and `double`).

Now your code doesn't actually talk about a flat fee of 40 cents - it's taking 0.4% of the original value. You should have something like:

```
decimal surcharge = 0.40m; // 40 cents
decimal total = moneyIn + surcharge;
```

Comment: I've changed that now but I get the error cannot convert source type double to target type decimal my moneyIn is a double because I've been told anything to do with money would be a data type double

Comment: @ScottAtkinson: No, anything to do with money should be `decimal`, not `double`... precisely because `double` cannot exactly represent values such as 0.1. If you're being asked to use `double` for currency values, you should push back *very hard*.

Comment: I see, I shall in the future, I'm not sure where I have gone wrong if I pass in 999.00m as mentioned the transaction fee would be 40 cents my code now looks like this surcharge = 0.40m * moneyIn

Comment: I need to calculates the surcharge (charge for processing the transaction).
    //  Surcharge Rates:
    //      - MasterCard = 1.2% for amounts up to and including 100, 1.0% for amounts over than 100
    //      - Visa = 1.0%
    //      - Amex = 3.1%
    //      - All others = 40 cent flat fee
    //
     For example:
        - input: "Visa", 10.0m   - output: 0.10

Comment: please see above I incorrectly wrote my question wrong

Comment: @ScottAtkinson: It's entirely unclear what you're actually asking for now - code for all of those different things? I've shown you what the code looks like for a 40 cent flat fee - if you need help with the other options, I suggest you ask a new question.